# Vagrant: missing file id_rsa

Tags: vagrant, homestead, vagrant-windows

I'm using windows with homestead and I'm trying to enter vagrant up on the command line but I'm getting this error:

> C:/www/Homestead/scripts/homestead.rb:106:in `read': No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - C:/Users/Niall/.ssh/id_rsa (Errno::ENOENT)
>           from C:/www/Homestead/scripts/homestead.rb:106:in`block (2 levels) in configure'
>           from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/plugins/kernel_v2/config/vm_provisioner.rb:72:in `call'
>           from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/plugins/kernel_v2/config/vm_provisioner.rb:72:in`add_config'
>           from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/plugins/kernel_v2/config/vm.rb:321:in `provision'
>           from C:/www/Homestead/scripts/homestead.rb:103:in`block in configure'
>           from C:/www/Homestead/scripts/homestead.rb:102:in `each'
>           from C:/www/Homestead/scripts/homestead.rb:102:in`configure'
>           from C:/www/Homestead/Vagrantfile:20:in `block in <top (required)>'
>           from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/config/v2/loader.rb:37:in`call'
>           from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/config/v2/loader.rb:37:in `load'
>           from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/config/loader.rb:113:in`block (2 levels) in load'
>           from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/config/loader.rb:107:in `each'
>           from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/config/loader.rb:107:in`block in load'
>           from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/config/loader.rb:104:in `each'
>           from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/config/loader.rb:104:in`load'
>           from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/vagrantfile.rb:28:in `initialize'
>           from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:740:in`new'
>           from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:740:in `vagrantfile'
>           from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:486:in`host'
>           from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:208:in `block in action_runner'
>           from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:33:in`call'
>           from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:33:in `run'
>           from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:473:in`hook'
>           from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:722:in `unload'
>           from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/bin/vagrant:177:in`ensure in '
>           from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/bin/vagrant:177:in `'

I searched online but all I could find was someone else asking the same question but no answer. What does this error mean? I went to the folder in particular and indeed there is no file called id_rsa. Can anyone shine some light on how to rectify this?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It looks like you need to generate an SSH key? You can do that by entering the command `ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "your_email@example.com"` (with your own email obviously) if you're using Git Bash.

When it prompts you for where to save the key just hit enter. Passphrase is also optional, just hit enter twice for a blank passphrase.

Comment: Lifesaver! This should be added to the installation docs for Laravel.

Comment: Sweet - would have never ever guessed this.

Comment: Useful answer, tks!

Comment: Note: if you have Cygwin (or msysgit) on Windows, you may have your ssh files elsewhere like so:

authorize: C:\dev\cygwin\home\myCYGWINusername\.ssh\id_rsa.pub

keys:
    - C:\dev\cygwin\home\myCYGWINusername\.ssh\id_rsa

Comment: Saved me hours of banging my head against the wall!