# Can't set up Laravel, vagrant up doesn't work

Tags: php, laravel, vagrant, homestead

I want to start a project with Laravel, but the set up before any work is just horrendous. I'm watching this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bC8OjU5ZlJQ and right around the 11:35 mark I just get this: [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mKRNR.png)

This is how my Homestead.yaml is configured:

```
authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
- ~/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
- map: ~/web/sites
  to: /home/vagrant/sites

sites:
- map: test.app
  to: /home/vagrant/sites/test

databases:
- homestead
```

Don't really know what I'm doing wrong, any help is appreciated!

**EDIT:** duplicate of [Vagrant: missing file id_rsa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35475503/vagrant-missing-file-id-rsa?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: Looks like `D:/web/.ssh/id_rsa` is missing.

Comment: where should I add it?

Comment: right where its telling you too

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Vagrant: missing file id\_rsa](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35475503/vagrant-missing-file-id-rsa)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create public key. You can [use `ssh-keygen` command for this](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-Generating-Your-SSH-Public-Key):

`$ ssh-keygen
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Enter file in which to save the key (/home/schacon/.ssh/id_rsa):
Created directory '/home/schacon/.ssh'.
Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase):
Enter same passphrase again:
Your identification has been saved in /home/schacon/.ssh/id_rsa.
Your public key has been saved in /home/schacon/.ssh/id_rsa.pub.
The key fingerprint is:
d0:82:24:8e:d7:f1:bb:9b:33:53:96:93:49:da:9b:e3 schacon@mylaptop.local`

Comment: Yup, this fixed it. While watching the video i generated an SSH key, but it didin't create and store itself in the D:/web/.ssh folder. Thanks a bunch man!